# GUI is getting hanged after calling the reader thread

Tags: java, multithreading, jbutton, telnet, flush

GUI is getting hanged after calling the reader thread for Telnet Client read operation through Jbutton.

Telnet read and write operation:

```
public class Telnet {
static TelnetClient telnet;
    public static void halt() {

    telnet = new TelnetClient();

    try {
        telnet.connect("000.000.0.000", 4444);
        String cmd = "halt \r";
        telnet.getOutputStream().write(cmd.getBytes());
        } catch{}

   readWrite(telnet.getInputStream(), telnet.getOutputStream(),
            System.in, System.out);

    try {
        telnet.disconnect(); 
    } catch {}
}

public static final void readWrite(final InputStream remoteInput,
                                   final OutputStream remoteOutput,
                                   final InputStream localInput,
                                   final OutputStream localOutput)
{
    Thread reader, writer;

    reader = new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            int ch;
            try
            {
                while (!interrupted() && (ch = localInput.read()) != -1)
                {
                    System.out.println("!interrupted() && (ch = localInput.read()) != -1");
                    remoteOutput.write(ch);
                    System.out.println("remote output write ch ");
                    remoteOutput.flush();
                    System.out.println("flushed");  
                }
            }catch{}
        }
    };
    writer = new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                Util.copyStream(remoteInput, localOutput);

            }
            catch {}
        }
    };
    writer.setPriority(Thread.currentThread().getPriority() + 1);
    writer.start();
    reader.setDaemon(true);
    reader.start();
    try
    {
        writer.join();
        reader.interrupt();
    }
    catch {}
}
```

}

GUI code:

```
private void haltPanel() throws Exception {

    halt = new JButton("HALT");
    halt.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            try{
                    Telnet.halt();
                }catch{}
        }
    });
}
```

I feel the reader thread is waiting for interrupt and not coming out of while loop while (!interrupted() && (ch = localInput.read()) != -1). How to come out of the loop after reading the input from Jbutton?
These are the prints I'm getting after GUI hang.

```
!interrupted() && (ch = localInput.read()) != -1
remote output write ch 
flushed
!interrupted() && (ch = localInput.read()) != -1
remote output write ch 
flushed
```

Please help me solve this and Thanks in advance.

Comment: a) never silently swallow exceptions `} catch{}`

Comment: You can't call a thread.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [Scary Wombat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2310289/scary-wombat): always log, or at least print your exceptions. Otherwise you'll never know what went wrong.

Anyway, you can run long-running processes in a background thread. It's even better to have an `ExecutorService` that handles `Threads` for you. The best option is to have one `ExecutorService`, i.e. one `Thread` pool for your app. This way your app is going to be efficient with the threads.

Here is an example code:

```
// this could go into a global utility class
// or injected wherever needed
final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

halt.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // () -> {} is a shorthand for new Runnable() {...}
        executor.submit(() -> {
            try {
                Telnet.halt();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                // catch the exception and print it
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }

};
```